# How to define return value for PHP's gethostname() in nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have a staging environment where I would like to use php's gethostname() to determine which machine I am running.

It is returning "mydomain.com" when I want "stg.mydomain.com".

I am running nginx on ubuntu. I have tried to edit "/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params"

with values like:

```
fastcgi_param  HOSTNAME          stg.mydomain.com;
fastcgi_param  HTTP_HOST          stg.mydomain.com;
fastcgi_param  HOST_NAME          stg.mydomain.com;
```

After restarting nginx, I see these values being populated in $_SERVER, but gethostname() continues to return the original value.

I can't find where or how this value is being set or how to override it.

Comment: That would be expected, because the server knows its name to be `mydomain.com` at its lowest level. If you want the HTTP_HOST from CGI, get it from `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`  PHP's `gethostname()` is intended to work at a deeper level than web applications and returns a value similar to just calling `hostname` on the command line.

Comment: But is there no way to update the server at its lowest level to know itself as "stg.mydomain.com" instead? I'm not wedded to updating the fastcgi_params as the means to accomplish this. I have full control over the server.

Comment: only if you actually changed the server's OS configuration like setting `sudo hostname stg.mydomain.com` or editing `/etc/hostname` if that's what you want to do. It is a matter of the OS reporting itself to PHP as stg.mydomain.com so if it is appropriate for the server to be named that way, you can change it there.

Comment: Perfect!. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you. Do you want to create an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by [`gethostname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php) is the server's hostname as the operating system reports it, similar to what would be returned if you ran the command `hostname` without arguments at the command line.

This means it also operates at a level deeper than any web application served over HTTP with regard to what the hostname is.  If the server's hostname as the OS currently knows it is correct for the server itself, then you should instead get the correct `HTTP_HOST` or `SERVER_NAME` cgi variables from the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

But if the server's OS is not reporting the name it should at the deeper OS layer, you may change it according to the correct method for your system.  Once it reports the correct name via `hostname` on the command line, PHP's `gethostname()` will too.

You may modify `/etc/hostname` and reboot the system, or with a root shell

```
$ sudo hostname stg.mydomain.com
```

which will probably also require a reboot to make sure the running state is consistent across all daemons.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [`runkit_function_redefine()`](http://php.net/runkit_function_redefine) to redefine `gethostname()`.